# Using replace string method inside forEach

Tags: javascript

I have an array full of strings which I'd like to loop over and replace any occurrences of '123' with ''.

The desired result would be: `['hello', 'cats', 'world', 'dogs']`

```
let arr = ['he123llo', 'cats', 'wor123ld', 'dogs'];

arr.forEach(x => {
  x.replace('123', '');
});
```

Comment: `const replacedStrings = arr.map(word => word.replace(/123/g, ''))`

Comment: `forEach()` returns `undefined`, you're supposed to use `Array.prototype.map()` insted and, by the way, it's better to use `.replace(/123/g, '')` if you want to replace ***all*** occurrences of unneeded substring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.map` instead, if you can - return the `.replace` call in the callback:

```js
let arr = ['he123llo', 'cats', 'wor123ld', 'dogs'];

const result = arr.map(x => x.replace('123', ''));
console.log(result);
```

If you have to mutate the array in-place, then take the index as well, and assign the `.replace` call back to that index in the array:

```js
let arr = ['he123llo', 'cats', 'wor123ld', 'dogs'];

arr.forEach((x, i) => arr[i] = x.replace('123', ''));
console.log(arr);
```