# Vanilla JS - .replace() with array and loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, lang

I wrote myself a little script that converts English words to Elvish words.

```js
var clickMe = document.querySelector('#button-7993f34d');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var checkSelect = document.querySelector("select");
    // Lang
    checkSelect.innerHTML = checkSelect.innerHTML.replace('Tree', 'Adahl');
    checkSelect.innerHTML = checkSelect.innerHTML.replace('Forest', 'Adahlen');
    checkSelect.innerHTML = checkSelect.innerHTML.replace('Arrow', 'Assan');
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Tree</option>
  <option>Forest</option>
  <option>Arrow</option>
</select>
<button id="button-7993f34d">click me</button>
```

Everything works fine. However, I would like to present the words in the form of an array. For example:

```
langs = [
  {"eng": "Tree", "elf": "Adahl"},
  {"eng": "Forest", "elf": "Adahlen"},
  {"eng": "Arrow", "elf": "Assan"}
]
```

And not repeat it:

```
 checkSelect.innerHTML = checkSelect.innerHTML.replace('Tree', 'Adahl');
```

This thread was closest to my solution:
[Using replace string method inside forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162350/using-replace-string-method-inside-foreach)
However, I was unable to adapt it to my script.

Is it possible in my case? I tried to find a similar solution with the replace function. Unfortunately, to no avail. Can you advise something?

Still, I keep trying, if I find a solution before answering, I will definitely share it.

Comment: _"However, I was unable to adapt it to my script."_ - Where's that attempt? -> [mcve]

Comment: Why is `langs` an array of objects with one object per word? Why not a single object with `{ <english word>: <elvish word> }` -> `{ "Tree": "Adahl", "Forest": "Adahlen", ... }` ? -> `Object.entries()`

Comment: Replacing the innerHTML is a bad idea, it makes a lot of internal work, and may lead to dataloss. You should consider to split the element text to textNodes, and overwrite the text content of the textNodes only.

Comment: Would you like to use a special tool for internationalization, such as [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/)? This is a kind of versatile tool for both a small site and a major project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic function that replaces occurrences of your english terms with elvish terms.

```js
function replaceText(text) {
  const langs = [
    {"eng": "Tree", "elf": "Adahl"},
    {"eng": "Forest", "elf": "Adahlen"},
    {"eng": "Arrow", "elf": "Assan"}
  ];
  let textToReturn = text;
  langs.forEach((word) => {
    textToReturn = textToReturn.replaceAll(word.eng, word.elf);
  });
  return textToReturn;
};

console.log(replaceText("My Tree is in the Forest"));
```

Comment: This solution helped me the most. Thank you Mario! Link to solve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n4x3dcwz/

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a switch statement.

```
switch(wordInEnglish) {

    case "Tree": return "Adahl";
    
    case "Forrest": return "Adahlen";

    case "Arrow": return "Assan";

}
```